# Coefficients for Cayley-Hamilton theorem

Tags: matlab, coefficients

Hello I am new to Matlab and a bit confused regarding the implementation of the Caley Hamilton using Matlab. Lets assume we have a matrix A which is known. I am trying to find the coefficients a,b,c such that

```
A^3 = a*I + b*A + c*A^2
where I is the identity
```

Is there a specific command where I can just insert them?  Or I have to basically solve it like I do it in paper?
I have tried the following

```
I = eye(3,3);

syms a1 b c 
eqn1 = c*A^2 + b*A + a1*I - A^3 ==0;
S1 = solve(eqn1)
```

but how can I verify that the return is correct? Because as a return I get
and S1 struct variable with 3 values inside a1 = 106 , b = 13 , c = -6

Comment: I assume you just want to solve `0 = a*I + b*A + c*A^2- A^3`. There are several ways of doing this, search for "solve equation matlab"

Comment: Hello @AnderBiguri thank you for the reply. I edited the question because I found about the page you posted and tried one method but I do not know if it is correct

Comment: The result is correct, otherwise `solve` would not have returned :D. But you can just go and try the left hand side of that equation with the values, to see if it is zero.